# docker-py: How to get exit code returned by process running inside container?

Tags: docker, dockerpy

My python script uses `docker-py` to launch a docker container as follows:

```
client = docker.from_env()
result = client.containers.run(
    image="my-prog-image:latest",
    command=["/etc/my-prog/configs.ini"],
    auto_remove=True,
    network_mode="host",
)
```

As documented [docker-py: containers](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/containers.html), the `client.containers.run(...)` method returns container. How can I retrieve exit code returned by `my-prog` running inside container?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`result.wait()`](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/containers.html#docker.models.containers.Container.wait) should wait for the container to run to completion, then return its exit code.

However, you'll probably hit some trouble with this since you specify `auto_remove=True` but do not specify `detach=True`.  `run()` without `detach=True` will run the container to completion, then the `auto_remove=True` option will delete the container, and at that point the status code doesn't exist any more.  You might split these steps up explicitly:

```py
client = docker.from_env()
container = client.containers.run(
    image="my-prog-image:latest",
    command=["/etc/my-prog/configs.ini"],
    detach=True,
)
result = container.wait()
container.remove()
```

(In Docker CLI terms, you've done `docker run --rm ...` and then are trying to find the container's result with `docker ps -a`, but the container is gone; I suggest changing it to `docker run -d ...` without `--rm`, checking the `docker ps` output, and then manually `docker rm` the container.  Actually, there's even a [`docker wait` CLI command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/wait/) but it's rarely used.)

Comment: And `exit_code = result["StatusCode"]`. Sorry for very late response.

Comment: Thank you. Got exactly what I was looking for. Cheers!